# How to delete an object in an S3 Bucket when file has been deleted locally in PHP

Tags: php, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I am trying to implement a feature which would help delete an object in my s3 bucket at the click of a button on my website. So far i have been able to successfully implement uploading of files, but deleting them using the AWS SDK for php seems impossible. Below is what i have implemented.

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

class Delete{
function deleteS3object(string $bucketname, string $keyfilename){

   $bucket = $bucketname;
   $keyname = $keyfilename;
   
   $s3 = new S3Client([
       'version' => 'latest',
       'region'  => 'us-east-2'
   ]);
   
   // 1. Delete the object from the bucket.
   try
   {
       echo 'Attempting to delete ' . $keyname . '...' . PHP_EOL;
   
       $result = $s3->deleteObject([
           'Bucket' => $bucket,
           'Key'    => $keyname
       ]);
   
       if ($result['DeleteMarker'])
       {
           echo $keyname . ' was deleted or does not exist.' . PHP_EOL;
       } else {
           exit('Error: ' . $keyname . ' was not deleted.' . PHP_EOL);
       }
   }
   catch (S3Exception $e) {
       exit('Error: ' . $e->getAwsErrorMessage() . PHP_EOL);
   }
   
   // 2. Check to see if the object was deleted.
   try
   {
       echo 'Checking to see if ' . $keyname . ' still exists...' . PHP_EOL;
   
       $result = $s3->getObject([
           'Bucket' => $bucket,
           'Key'    => $keyname
       ]);
   
       echo 'Error: ' . $keyname . ' still exists.';
   }
   catch (S3Exception $e) {
       exit($e->getAwsErrorMessage());
   } 
   
   return;
}
}

$x =  new Delete();
$success = $x->deleteS3object('bucketname', 'file.png') ? 'deleted': 'Error';
echo $success;
?>
```

But it returns a 500 error notice for me, is there anything am possibly doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think i understand what my mistake was now, in the S3Client initialization, i failed to provide the necessary credentials, which is the

> key and secret_key

, so i added those lines and it worked Perfectly. Here is a working solution below.

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Aws\S3\S3Client;
use Aws\S3\Exception\S3Exception;

class Delete{
function deleteS3object(string $bucketname, string $keyfilename){

   $bucket = $bucketname;
   $keyname = $keyfilename;
   
   $s3 = new S3Client([
      'region'  => 'us-east-2',
      'version' => 'latest',
      'credentials' => [
         'key'    => "key",
         'secret' => "secretkey",
      ]
   ]);
   
   // 1. Delete the object from the bucket.
   try
   {
       echo 'Attempting to delete ' . $keyname . '...' . PHP_EOL;
   
       $result = $s3->deleteObject([
           'Bucket' => $bucket,
           'Key'    => $keyname
       ]);
   
       if ($result['DeleteMarker'])
       {
           echo $keyname . ' was deleted or does not exist.' . PHP_EOL;
       } else {
           exit('Error: ' . $keyname . ' was not deleted.' . PHP_EOL);
       }
   }
   catch (S3Exception $e) {
       exit('Error: ' . $e->getAwsErrorMessage() . PHP_EOL);
   }
   
   // 2. Check to see if the object was deleted.
   try
   {
       echo 'Checking to see if ' . $keyname . ' still exists...' . PHP_EOL;
   
       $result = $s3->getObject([
           'Bucket' => $bucket,
           'Key'    => $keyname
       ]);
   
       echo 'Error: ' . $keyname . ' still exists.';
   }
   catch (S3Exception $e) {
       exit($e->getAwsErrorMessage());
   } 
   
   return;
}
}

$x =  new Delete();
$success = $x->deleteS3object('bucketname', 'file.png') ? 'deleted': 'Error';
echo $success;
?>
```